# RegEx for swiss phone number

Tags: php, regex, validation, laravel-4, phone-number

I need a RegEx to do the validation (using Laravel, a php framework) for a swiss phone number which has to fit this format:

+41 11 111 11 11

The "+41" part has to be exactly this way while the rest (11 111 11 11) can be any number between 1 and 9.

The function that invokes the RegEx looks like this:

```
    $regex = "thisIsWhereINeedYourHelp";

    if (preg_match($regex, $value)) {
               return true;
            } 
    return true;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation?rq=1

Answer (score 10):

This is the pattern I use:

```
/(\b(0041|0)|\B\+41)(\s?\(0\))?(\s)?[1-9]{2}(\s)?[0-9]{3}(\s)?[0-9]{2}(\s)?[0-9]{2}\b/
```

it  matches all the following:

```
+41 11 111 11 11
+41 (0) 11 111 11 11
+41111111111
+41(0)111111111
00411111111
0041 11 111 11 11
0041 (0) 11 111 11 11
011 111 11 11
0111111111
```

any of the spaces can be left out and it checks for the word and non word boundaries.

Comment: in case you only want to match numbers with country prefix, starting with 0041 or +41 
`/(\b(0041)|\B\+41)(\s?\(0\))?(\s)?[1-9]{2}(\s)?[0-9]{3}(\s)?[0-9]{2}(\s)?[0-9]{2}\b/`

Comment: This regex here works as opposed to the answer https://gist.github.com/peyerluk/8357036

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as:

`(\+41)\s(\d{2})\s(\d{3})\s(\d{2})\s(\d{2})`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/hJ9oY0

Comment: Change each `\s` to `\s?` if you want to match `+41 00 111 22 33` and also `+41001112233`

Comment: Yes ideally you want to be able to accept numbers seperated with/without spaces or also with hyphens

Comment: @sshashank124 hyphens are not a thing in the swiss telepohone realm

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex which would work fine with a Swiss Phone Number:

```
^(\+?)(\d{2,4})(\s?)(\-?)((\(0\))?)(\s?)(\d{2})(\s?)(\-?)(\d{3})(\s?)(\-?)(\d{2})(\s?)(\-?)(\d{2})
```

Comment: In Switzerland, we never write phone numbers with a hyphen, so you could actually omit every `(\-?)` in this regex

Answer (score 2):

I first cleanup the string a bit (that avoids useless matches):

```
// input string cleanup
$input = preg_replace('/[^0-9+\(\)-]/', '', $input);
```

I than match a swiss number:

```
// swiss telephone validation +41 (0)xx xxx xxxx
if(preg_match('/^(\+41|0041|0){1}(\(0\))?[0-9]{9}$/',$input))
        $result = "match: CH";
else    $result = "no match";
```

this should match all swiss formats and be fairly reliable

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Laravel-Phone](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Phone) package for Validation, Formatting and more functionality.

In your case you can specify you country like this :

```
'phone' => 'required|phone:CH'
```

*CH = Switzerland (Confoederatio Helvetica)*